# Is SQL and PPL fully supported?

Tags: aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I tried a few queries and found that some of the SQL queries are working while some are not.

I uploaded test data using dev tools. I have uploaded a few hundred documents (crwaler) as well.

```
PUT /library/book/_bulk?refresh&pretty
{"index":{"_id": "Leviathan Wakes"}}
{"name": "Leviathan Wakes", "author": "James S.A. Corey", "release_date": "2011-06-02", "page_count": 561}
{"index":{"_id": "Hyperion"}}
{"name": "Hyperion", "author": "Dan Simmons", "release_date": "1989-05-26", "page_count": 482}
{"index":{"_id": "Dune"}}
{"name": "Dune", "author": "Frank Herbert", "release_date": "1965-06-01", "page_count": 604}
```

1. This works correctly and shows the indices.

```
SHOW tables LIKE %;

.kibana_1
cwl-2021.01.05
library
```

2. This works as well. Shows 42 records.

```
select * from .kibana_1;
```

This works as expected:

```
select * from library where page_count > 500 and name = 'Dune'
```

3. This does not work:

```
select * from cwl-2021.01.05
```

Getting an error "no response"

4. This works but shows only 200 records out of 400:

```
select * from cwl*
```

5. This works only if the ID is within the first 200 records:

```
select * from cwl* where requestID = '3FB4131539FD4403'
```

---

The pipe query language works as expected only with library index.

```
search source=library page_count > 500 and name = 'Dune'
```

It does not work with other indices like .kibana_1 or cwl-2021.01.05

I am not sure how SQL and PPL is supported in AWS elasticsearch instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use backtick for this user case. e.g.

```
POST /_opendistro/_ppl
{
  "query": """
    source=`filebeat-7.10.0-2020.11.28`
  """
}
```

Comment: backticks work with PPL but not with SQL. https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/sql/issues/976

Comment: You could enable the new engine on ODFE 1.12 which support the backticks.
[opendistro.sql.engine.new.enabled](https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/sql/blob/develop/docs/user/admin/settings.rst#opendistro-sql-engine-new-enabled)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this reference for delimiting identifiers for using special chars.

https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/sql/blob/develop/docs/experiment/ppl/general/identifiers.rst#delimited-identifiers

More on documentation:

Sql : https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/sql/blob/develop/docs/user/index.rst

Ppl : https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/sql/blob/develop/docs/experiment/ppl/index.rst

Contributions: https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/sql/blob/develop/docs/developing.rst

Forums: https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/c/sql/8

Sql/ppl : are both developed in the open source and used as-is in the aws service.

Comment: showing a "no response" message for any (or every) error is not an intuitive way of programming, by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because SQL and PPL does not like special characters like dot or dash in table name.

```
PUT /cwl-2021.01.06/_alias/cwl20210106

PUT /cwl-2021.01.07/_alias/cwl20210107
```

I created an alias and now everything seems to be working as expected.

> select * from cwl20210107 where eventID = 'xxx' limit 100

All the beats, crawlers (by default) have the special chars in their index names. It is not easy to change the index name. :)